# How to uniquely Identify objects in Python so that we can Insert Nodes in a Queue?

Tags: python, oop, artificial-intelligence

Currently I was trying to solve the 8 Tile Problem using the A* Algorithm, the heuristic function was the number of inversions in the Matrix provided, As I am adding the Nodes and their states to a queue I need to be able to uniquely identify them for this purpose I am using the __eq__() function in the Node Class.
However the program seems to not be able to separate two similar instances and enters into an infinite loop.

The central issue according to me is the fact that I am not able to correctly identify the values and see the difference between them.
I am using a queue instead of a pq as I am new to them currently.

So could you please help me understand where I am going wrong.

```
import random

cols = 3;
rows = 3;

l = [i for i in range(9)];
random.shuffle(l);

initial = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)];

k = 0;
for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
                initial[i][j] = l[k];
                k += 1;
print(initial);         


arr = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]
for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
                arr[i][j] = 3*i + j;



class Node:
        def __init__(self,s,p,d):
                self.state = s.copy();
                self.parent = p;
                self.g = 0;
                self.isDummy = d;
                if(p is not None):
                        self.g = p.g + 1;
                
        def __eq__(self,other):
                l = self.state.copy()
                k= other.state.copy()
                for i in range(3):
                        for j in range(3):
                                if(l[i][j] != k[i][j]):
                                        return False;
                return True;
        def checkInversion(self):
                invert = 0;
                l = [];
                for i in range(3):
                        for j in range(3):
                                l.append(self.state[i][j]);
                for i in range(len(l)):
                        for j in range(i+1,len(l)):
                                if(l[j] != 0 and l[i] > l[j]):
                                        invert += 1;
                return invert;
                
        def isViable(self):
                return self.checkInversion()%2 == 0; 
        def createChild(self,move1,move2,index):
                x = 0;
                y = 0;
                global rows;
                global cols;
                l = self.state.copy()
                for i in range(3):
                        for j in range(3):
                                if(l[i][j] == 0):
                                        x = i;
                                        y = j;
                j = x + move1[index];
                k = y + move2[index];
                lis = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)];
                for i in range(3):
                        for j in range(3):
                                lis[i][j] = self.state[i][j];
                if(j < 0 or j > 2):
                        return Node(lis,self,True);
                if (k < 0 or k > 2):
                        return Node(lis,self,True);
                
                temp = lis[x][y];
                lis[x][y] = lis[j][k];
                lis[j][k] = temp;
                return Node(lis,self,False);
        
        def h(self):
                return self.checkInversion();
        def f(self):
                return self.g + self.h();
        def isGoal(self):
                global Goal
                if(self.state == Goal.state):
                  return True;
                return False;
        def checkExplored(self,l):
                n = len(l);
                for i in range(n):
                        if(l[i] == self):
                                return False;
                return True;
        
        def show(self):
                print(self.state);



        
Goal = Node(arr,None,False);
def AStar(source):
        if(source.isGoal()):
                return True;
        q = [];
        move1 = [1,0,-1,0];
        move2 = [0,1,0,-1];
        q.append(source);
        explored = [];
        while(q):
                cur = q[0];
                mi = 0;
                for i in range(len(q)):
                        if(q[i].f() < cur.f()):
                                cur = q[i];
                                mi  = i;
                a = q.pop(mi);
                a.show();
                if(a.isGoal()):
                        return a;
                explored.append(a);
                
                for i in range(4):
                        child = a.createChild(move1,move2,i);
                        if(child.isDummy):
                                continue;
                        flag = False;
                        flag2 = False;
                        for j in range(len(explored)):
                                if(child == explored[j]):
                                        flag2 = True;
                        if(not flag2):
                                for j in range(len(q)):
                                        if(child == q[j]):      
                                                flag = True;
                                                if(child.g < q[j].g):
                                                        q[j].g = child.g;
                        if(not flag):
                                q.append(child);
                  
                                
k = Node(initial,None,False);
#print(k.isGoal());
print(k.checkInversion());
a = Node(initial,None,False);
if(k.checkInversion()%2 == 0):
        a = AStar(k);
#print(a);
a.show()
enter code here
```

Comment: Prefer 4-space [indentation](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) per PEP8.

Comment: Where do you think the infinite loop is?

Comment: I think the infinite loop is due to the fact that we are adding the same state to the queue again and again.

Comment: Another issue that I noticed is that even though the equality function returns True or False the queue is not able to reciprocate that behaviour.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to reduce this code down to the minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Removing the entire complexity of the queuing code, for example, if the issue is simply that your code to test if two objects are equal or unequal is not working.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I kind of figured that the major issue in the code was due to the explored list so I checked everyone before appending them into explored and also made my equality function a bit more direct. This helped me deal with the problem (The time taken for a randomly generated problem is 2 minutes maximum as of now).Thanks.